# Jomsocial email alert at event creation

Tags: events, joomla3.0, jomsocial

If I create an event in a Jomsocial group, I'll automatically get a notification email, if I'm part of that group.

Can this function be replicated in ordinary events, so everybody on my Jomsocial network will get an email upon an event creation, even though they are not part of a group?

Comment: There will be some code which will be causing this.. try to find the file associated with the event creation..